# Find issues that were ever assigned to me

Tags: jira

I am trying to create a filter to search for all issues that were ever assigned to me, even after the assignee is changed. I cant find the appropriate search parameters for this. Is it even possible in jira?

Comment: Which JIRA version do you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find issues that at some point has been assigned to you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145913/how-to-find-issues-that-at-some-point-has-been-assigned-to-you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the toolkit plugin
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JTOOL/JIRA+Toolkit+Plugin

It has a custom field 'Participant' which allows you to find all issues
that you raised, were assigned to or commented on.

Francis

Comment: It seems the toolkit plugin URL has changed and is currently: [https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/5142/toolkit-plugin-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/5142/toolkit-plugin-for-jira?hosting=server&tab=overview)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 227):

`assignee was currentUser()` should do it.

It will also include issues that are currently assigned to you.

If it doesn't, try: `(assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser())`

Comment: Sorry I am new to JIRA.  I'm looking at the web interface and I have no idea how I would make this work.  Is there some place where I c+p this?  Could you provide some additional instructions?

Comment: When seeing a list of issues, press "Edit" on the left sidebar to edit the query.

Comment: on a page with list of issues, you need to click on "Advanced" search

Comment: I find that the `was` search also brings up my currently assigned tickets.

Comment: How can I sort from date of assignment?

Comment: "assignee was currentUser()" will find also the issues that are currently assigned to the user.

Thus you can drop "assignee = currentUser() OR" and the result will still be the same. No need for it.

Comment: And if you want to exclude currently assigned tickets then use `(assignee was currentUser() AND NOT assignee = currentUser())`.

Answer (score 41):

I'm not sure if things have changed with JIRA since previous answers were written, but all I needed was:

```
assignee was currentUser()
```

This will pick up things that are currently or previously assigned to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its really frustrating to see that default Jira UI doesn't have any hint how to do that because its generally a very important requirement.

Comment: The best answer.

Comment: I was looking for something similar, but specifically for tickets assigned to me as the developer. This worked for me: `developer in (currentUser())`

Answer (score 25):

- Click the eyeglass icon on the left pane
- Click on "Advanced search for issues"
- In the top right, click on "Advanced Search" to open the JQL textbox
- Enter the query:

```
assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser()
```

If you'll use this repeatedly, click save and name the search. Then you'll see it on the left bar under Starred...

Answer (score 7):

2022 and still the solution works like a charm for jira version 8.20.6

```
assignee was currentUser()
```

Answer (score 2):

> issue in watchedIssues()

... might also be of use. It gets every issue relevant to you.

Comment: Actually it gets all issues where the current user is a watcher. Other  relevant issues won't be returned.

Answer (score -1):

On the JIRA web application/site navigate to Issues (in header) > Search for issues, then enter your search criteria.