# JIRA: Find all issues that were at some point assigned to user while in specific status

Tags: jira, jql

I am looking for a query that lets me search through JIRA for all issues that belonged to a user at any point *while in a specific status*.

For example, say that when work is finished, issues get set to a "Code Review" status and assigned to user X who is responsible for performing the code review. After code review is completed, the issue is assigned to someone else.

If I at some point want to know all issues that were ever reviewed by user X, how can I accomplish this?

I have found solutions to this problem if you don't care about what status the issue was in when it was assigned to a user, but not if you care about the status.

[How to find issues that at some point has been assigned to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145913/how-to-find-issues-that-at-some-point-has-been-assigned-to-you)

[Find issues that were ever assigned to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582877/find-issues-that-were-ever-assigned-to-me)

The closest query that I am aware of is

```
assignee was 'user X'
```

but this will get all issues that were assigned to the user in *any* status.

Can I accomplish this without adding an extra field for storing the code reviewer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution that doesn't meet the question exactly as asked, but is relatively close.

Say there are two transitions out of the "Code Review" status, one that leads to a status called "Failed Code Review" and another that leads to a status called "Passed Code Review". The following query gets all issues that have been set to either of these statuses by a given user.x:

```
(status WAS "Failed Code Review" BY user.x) OR (status WAS "Passed Code Review" BY user.x)
```

This does not work perfectly however, as it will

- also get all issues set to those statuses by user.x from any other transition
- not get any issues that were assigned to user.x in "Code Review", but transitioned to another status by another user