# JIRA: Find all issues related to a user

Tags: jira, jql, jira-filter

In JIRA, how do a find all issues related to a user, across all projects.

A simple query search yields only full text results. i.e. only issues where the name is mentioned and not if the name has been assigned, has reported, has been cc’d etc.

My intention here is to find tickets related to me for stock accounting.

I'm using JIRA 3.13.

Answer (score 73):

```
assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser()
```

This will suffice the query

Comment: Sorry, I am new to JIRA.  I'm looking at the web interface and I have no idea how I would make this work.  Is there some place where I c+p this?  Could you provide some additional instructions?
Your answer seems magical and mystical.  I've whispered these incantations to the server but no luck so far

Comment: @MedicineMan When seeing a list of issues, press "Edit" on the left sidebar to edit the query.

Comment: Not really sure how that differs from "find all issues related to a user", certainly if a user is a watcher on a ticket, then they are related to that ticket, no?

Comment: Go to search page by browsing to `/browse`

Comment: Add `OR worklogAuthor = currentUser()` for issues you logged on but was never assigned to

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same 'stock accounting' use case: If you like to get an overview of the issues where you were involved to, just go to the profile page of your user, and hit 'Activity'. All tickets you had been working on are displayed.

This seems to be an alternative for all who are also not able to do a query like

`assignee was currentUser()`

because their Jira does not support history searches on that field (like ours here).

Answer (score 5):

Like Greg mentioned, you can use the "FIND ISSUES" -option. By default, you can only do searches by the issue reporter or by the assignee. But if your Jira installation has the [Jira Toolkit plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JTOOL/JIRA+Toolkit+Plugin) installed, you can run a search by participant. This is a good feature if you need to find the issues which you have helped to resolve, but aren't anymore assigned to you.

Answer (score 5):

Click on Issues on the top, click New on the left bar.

Now, choose the reporter and assignee. Then switch to Advanced search.

Then you can change the AND to an OR and do the search.

e.g.

```
assignee = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser()
```

(it would have been `AND` by default)

Answer (score 4):

In JIRA, I need to find really all issues related to a user (me) including comments, assignee, reporter, watcher and status updates.

I've used filters with JQL and next query:

```
status changed BY currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser() 
OR watcher in (currentUser()) OR assignee = currentUser() 
OR assignee was currentUser() OR commentedByUser = currentUser() 
ORDER BY updated DESC
```

1. Open filter page:

[image: JIRA Filter]

2. Switch to `JQL`
   [image: Switch to JQL button]
3. Enter query and click `Search` button.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "FIND ISSUES" option across the top bar, select "New" to create a new filter (which by default spans all projects), and select your name from the relevant "Issue Attributes" dropdown boxes.

Comment: The problem with this kind is that it’s an AND condition and not OR. I can’t search for “Reporter” OR “Assignee” OR “CC” ..

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hammer:

> `watcher = currentUser() OR assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser() OR creator = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser() OR text ~ currentUser() OR summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser() ORDER BY updated DESC`

You could limit to some days:

> `updated > -365d AND (watcher = currentUser() OR assignee = currentUser() OR assignee was currentUser() OR creator = currentUser() OR reporter = currentUser() OR comment ~ currentUser() OR text ~ currentUser() OR summary ~ currentUser() OR description ~ currentUser()) ORDER BY updated DESC`

Answer (score -2):

Open the JIRA web application/site in your browser and navigate to Issues (in header) > Search for issues, then enter your search criteria.