# List of all jira tasks that I was assigner on

Tags: jira

How can I get list of all tasks that I **was** assigned?

I just need to know all the tasks despite its current status or assignee.

Is it possible?

Comment: Same topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145913/jira-how-to-find-issues-that-at-some-point-has-been-assigned-to-you

Comment: Workaround. "watch" all issues that is assigned to me, so later I can easy see all watched tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So here the answer to the changed question (tasks that I was assigned to):

- Depending on the version of JIRA, you are now able to asked questions that go into history. See the [example in the documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/JIRA+4.4.3+Release+Notes#JIRA443ReleaseNotes-MoreEnhancementstoJQL%C2%A0%E2%80%94NewCHANGEDOperatorandWASImprovements) and the documentation about the ["WAS operator"](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-WAS).

Your query should look like:

```
assignee WAS "wormhit" BEFORE "02/02/2011"
```

If you want to store your search (not the result), there are the following options:

- Define your own filter by saving a search like the one as "Own issues". Steps:

  - `Search > Edit > Issue Attributes > Assignee > Current User`
  - Switch on the top to tab `Summary`
  - Under `Operations`, press `Save it as filter`
  - Give it meaningful name.
  - The filter is now available under `Issues > Favorite Filters`
- You may store the shortcut for the search as a bookmark
  [image]

Comment: Thank you but sorry! I`m looking for query not way to save it for later use.

Comment: I got this error: "History searches do not support the 'assignee' field." But this is the right answer. Will accept this answer if nothing better arrives today.

Comment: For version 4.3 WAS can be used only on "status" field.
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-WAS

Comment: You might ant to use now() instead of a static date if you're using it as an ongoing widget.

Answer (score 3):

General-purpose query for whichever 'current user':

```
assignee was currentUser()
```

This filter can be conveniently shared & anybody can put it on their dashboard, etc and it will return results specific to them.. Requires a not-too-old JIRA version, though.

This was my most-requested JIRA feature *ever*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can add a gadget "my tasks" to your dashboard.

Or you can use JQL like:
assignee = %yourname%

**UPD** To find tasks you WAS assigned, use JQL: "assignee was %username%"

Comment: That way I can find tasks that is *currently* assigned to user. I want to find the same thing but in history. Like: last week task was assigned to me, and now it is assigned to other user.

Comment: I got this error: "History searches do not support the 'assignee' field."
But I understand that is because I have old jira version (v4.3.3) or something.

Answer (score 0):

Go like this:

`Issues` -> `search for issues` -> `Issue atrributes` -> `Assignee` -> `Current User` -> `Search`

Comment: It is the same thing what @AvrDragon was saying. But it is not what I'm looking for. I need a list of all issues I was assigned in the past, despite that current assignee is different user.

Answer (score 0):

By following [this](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-12312) discussin I stumbled on [HP/Palm Jira Search Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/338080) that can find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't see why this plugin is an answer to your own question. Perhaps it would be better to invest more in the question ...