# How can I find the tasks that I completed using JIRA

Tags: jira

I am trying to create JIRA filter as below

```
project = "ProjectA" AND status = Done
```

The problem is I am just a developer. Hence, all I do is develop it and then pass it along to tester. At that point the JIRA status changes from "In Progress" to "SIT" ....And finally to "Done".

I want to know how many tasks where actually completed by me in last 5 weeks or so using filter. Is that possible?

Comment: Found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145913/how-to-find-issues-that-at-some-point-has-been-assigned-to-you?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "changed" keyword - see here for details

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-CHANGED