# Which jira tasks were assigned to me?

Tags: jira

The requirement people assign me jira tasks to implement some issues or to fix bugs and when I have implemented the task, I assign the task to some tester.

Now I would like to find out, which tasks was assign to me in the current project / release to check the documentations. Any Idea how to do this? the "`Assigned to Me`" widget in jira shows me only the tasks, which are currently assigned to me.

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145913/how-to-find-issues-that-at-some-point-has-been-assigned-to-you?rq=1
JQL: project = "Project" and (assignee was 'Ronald')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Filter in JIRA. Create a filter with following query 
`assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved order by updated DESC`. It'll show you all the unresolved issues in JIRA, that's assigned to you. But make sure that you have logged into JIRA, with your credentials.

[image]